# session destroy to target a particular session variable

Tags: php, html, session

I'm using sessions in my website for both user log-in and adding items to a cart. i have a button empty cart that destroys the session to remove all items in the cart session, however when i do this the user is automatically logged out, so i was wondering how i delete the

```
 $_SESSION["cart"]
```

without destroying other sessions? what other ways can this be done without using session_destroy as that's not an option. I saw another question saying to use

```
 $this->Session->delete([cart]);
```

That doesn't work for me, i get the error:

```
Using $this when not in object context in 
/.../..../.../1000A.D/basket.php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
use unset function

unset($_SESSION["cart"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it to an empty value. ie `$_SESSION["cart"] = ''` That always works